# Android and YoutubePlayer : Error creating YouTubePlayerView

Tags: android, android-fragments, youtube, youtube-api, android-youtube-api

I am facing a problem with YoutubePlayer, I put it inside a fragment like this :

```
public class VideoFragment extends YouTubePlayerSupportFragment {

public VideoFragment() { }

public static Fragment newInstance(String url) {

    VideoFragment f = new VideoFragment();

    Bundle b = new Bundle();
    b.putString("url", url);

    f.setArguments(b);
    f.init(Constants.YOUTUBE_DEV_KEY);

    return f;
}

private void init(String api) {

    initialize(api, new YouTubePlayer.OnInitializedListener() {

        @Override
        public void onInitializationFailure(YouTubePlayer.Provider arg0, YouTubeInitializationResult arg1) { }

        @Override
        public void onInitializationSuccess(YouTubePlayer.Provider provider, YouTubePlayer player, boolean wasRestored) {
            if (!wasRestored) {
                player.cueVideo(getArguments().getString("url"));
            }
        }
    });
}
```

And I call it from my other fragment in this way :

```
Fragment f = VideoFragment.newInstance(User.getVideoId());
        getFragmentManager().beginTransaction().replace(R.id.fragment_container, f).commit();
```

However, i keep getting this error :

> YouTubeAndroidPlayerAPI: Error creating YouTubePlayerView
>                                                                                                  com.google.android.youtube.player.internal.w$a: Exception thrown by
>   invoked constructor in
>   com.google.android.youtube.api.jar.client.RemoteEmbeddedPlayer
>                                                                                                      at com.google.android.youtube.player.internal.w.a(Unknown Source)
>                                                                                                      at com.google.android.youtube.player.internal.w.a(Unknown Source)
>                                                                                                      at com.google.android.youtube.player.internal.w.a(Unknown Source)
>                                                                                                      at com.google.android.youtube.player.internal.ac.a(Unknown Source)
>                                                                                                      at com.google.android.youtube.player.YouTubePlayerView.a(Unknown
>   Source)
>                                                                                                      at com.google.android.youtube.player.YouTubePlayerView$1.a(Unknown
>   Source)
>                                                                                                      at com.google.android.youtube.player.internal.r.g(Unknown Source)
>                                                                                                      at com.google.android.youtube.player.internal.r$c.a(Unknown Source)
>                                                                                                      at com.google.android.youtube.player.internal.r$b.a(Unknown Source)
>                                                                                                      at
>   com.google.android.youtube.player.internal.r$a.handleMessage(Unknown
>   Source)....

Comment: Try to Import appcompat 23.0.1 instead of the latest version  as stated in [this site](http://www.mzan.com/article/33614190-youtubeplayersupportfragment-and-appcompatactivity-error.shtml).

Answer (score 0):

Not exactly a fix but if your app UX aloes it you can use YouTubeStandalonePlayer. I had the same issue with the YouTubePlayerActivity and the standalone player works.